# Tomcat's auto-deployment stopped working. Why?

Tags: tomcat

I removed `webapps/ROOT` directory, then unzip new version war into web apps. I found tomcat can receive request and JVM run normally, but web controllers cannot find JSP view when generating a response, the client got a 404 error。So it must restart the tomcat?

I operate like this:

```
rm -f -r tomcat/webapps/ROOT
unzip -qq /data/app/my.war -d tomcat/webapps/ROOT
```

The server.xml config:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
</Host>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to setup :

1. Keep a backup of the `ROOT` sub-folder from `webapps` folder so that if server crashes by any kind of change, you can revert back to your original state with that folder.
2. Then place your `.war` file in the `webapps` folder and then restart the server.

Note : If above steps is not working, then there might be problem with code.

Check in your `web.xml` of your project if below piece of configuration is present or not.

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        ......
 </welcome-file-list>
```

Please remove it because sometimes it interferes with the JSP rendering from the controllers.

Comment: Thanks. Restart tocmat can solve it. I donnot know why autodeploy failed. Web controllers work normally for jvm cache? Tomcat doesnot roload webapps directory in fact？

Comment: @Larry On startup, tomcat loads the `webapps` and deploys the folder present in that. If you delete any of the folder present in webapps while tomcat is running, then tomcat can't keep track. You might get some undesired outputs.

Comment: Yes !! you need to do that